# how to get beans from application context loaded by contextloaderlistener?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring/Spring Mvc and here's my problem. In my webapp, besides the spring-servlet.xml , I have a jdbc.xml which define beans like datasource, dao ... Before using contextloaderlistener , I load my jdbc.xml inside the Controller's constructor like this  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jdbcbeans.xml") then get the beans from that. But since I'm using contextloaderlistener to load the file, how can I get the reference to the context ? I was able to set up everything using those @Autowired things but I just want to know  is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html).

```
ApplicationContext context;
context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#web-integration-common) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to get an instance of Application Context 
in case of a container managed bean use `ApplicationContextAware` interface

```
    public class MyBean implements ApplicationContextAware {
       private static ApplicationContext context;     

     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext acontext) throws BeansException {
       context = context;
     }

     public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
       return context;
     }
   }
```

Or you can write the following

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext Context;
```

An instance of the Application Context will be autowired.